# jQgrid beforeProcessing doesn't fire

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-php, jqgrid-formatter

I am using  jqGrid  4.0.0, beforeProcessing never gets fired for each postBack, it has not been triggered at all, please assist!

```
$('#jqgInventory').jqGrid({
    autowidth: true,
    caption: 'Inventory',
    datatype:'json',
    forceFit: true,
    gridview: true,
    height: 500,
    hidegrid: false,
    ignoreCase: true,
    loadui: 'disable',
    pager:'#pager',
    mtype: 'post',
    rowNum:25,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    url:'/MCI/Inventory/Inventory/GetIndexGridData',
    viewrecords: true,
    postData: { modelView: JSON.stringify(model), __RequestVerificationToken:   $('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
    beforeProcessing:  function(data, status,xhr){beforeProcessing(data,status,xhr)},
    beforeRequest: function() {$('#gridScript').block();},
    beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) {return false;},
    gridComplete: function() {$('#lblVehicleCount').html($('#jqgInventory').getGridParam('records'));$('#gridScript').unblock();Inventory.modifyGridCellClick();},
    loadComplete: function(xhr) {GetGridData(xhr);},
```

Comment: I never used jqGrid, but which test have you run to determine that the before function never run?

Comment: there is an alert in beforeProcessing(data,status,xhr), will never fire

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use new features of jqGrid you should use the last version of jqGrid. You can download it from [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6).

The callback function `beforeProcessing` will be not called in jqGrid 4.0.0 because it was introduced in the version 4.2.0.